# EXC_BAD_ACCESS whilst parsing JSON using SBJSON. Corresponding message states variable json_string is not a CFString

Tags: iphone, json, nsstring

I have the following response from server side:

```
{"_playLists":[{"name":"Playlist 1","items":[{"name":"Poza 1","target":"http:\/\/myaudi.fr","url":"http:\/\/test.res-novae.fr\/sfrplay\/upload\/image\/pic1_iphone3.jpg","url_thumb":"http:\/\/test.res-novae.fr\/sfrplay\/upload\/thumb\/pic1_iphone3_thumb.jpg"},{"name":"Poza 2","target":"http:\/\/audifrance.fr","url":"http:\/\/test.res-novae.fr\/sfrplay\/upload\/image\/pic2_iphone3.jpg","url_thumb":"http:\/\/test.res-novae.fr\/sfrplay\/upload\/thumb\/pic2_iphone3_thumb.jpg"}]},{"name":"Playlist 2","items":[{"name":"Poza 3","target":"http:\/\/google.ro","url":null,"url_thumb":null}]}]}
```

And I'm trying to acces this by using:

```
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
```

But I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` at this line

```
 NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

saying variable `json_string` is not a `CFString`.

Can someone help me solve this and tell me how to act further to acces the JSON components?Thank you:)

EDIT:

```
{
        items =         (
                        {
                name = "Poza 1";
                target = "http://myaudi.fr";
                url = "http://test.res-novae.fr/sfrplay/upload/image/pic1_iphone3.jpg";
                "url_thumb" = "http://test.res-novae.fr/sfrplay/upload/thumb/pic1_iphone3_thumb.jpg";
            },
                        {
                name = "Poza 2";
                target = "http://audifrance.fr";
                url = "http://test.res-novae.fr/sfrplay/upload/image/pic2_iphone3.jpg";
                "url_thumb" = "http://test.res-novae.fr/sfrplay/upload/thumb/pic2_iphone3_thumb.jpg";
            }
        );
        name = "Playlist 1";
    },
        {
        items =         (
                        {
                name = "Poza 3";
                target = "http://google.ro";
                url = "<null>";
                "url_thumb" = "<null>";
            }
        );
        name = "Playlist 2";
    }
```

Comment: Do you get the same error when just calling `NSArray *statuses = [parser objectWithString:[request responseString] error:nil];`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use one of the JSON frameworks available out there, i.e. [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit)  or [json-framework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework), which both makes it really easy to convert strings to JSON objects (i.e. an `NSDictionary`).

If you're using json-framework, you'd only have to do the following (if you've included `JSON.h`):

```
NSDictionary *jsonObject = [responseString JSONValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need this line

```
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

responseString is already a string (and initWithData: expects a NSData object not NSString). Just feed it straight to the parser:

```
NSArray *statuses = [parser objectWithString:responseString error:nil];
```

> Can someone help me solve this and tell me how to act further to acces
>   the JSON components?

You now have a nice NSArray of NSDictionary objects representing your JSON data, you can access the first item, represented by

```
{"name":"Playlist 1","items":[{"name":"Poza 1","target":"http:\/\/myaudi.fr","url":"http:\/\/test.res-novae.fr\/sfrplay\/upload\/image\/pic1_iphone3.jpg","url_thumb":"http:\/\/test.res-novae.fr\/sfrplay\/upload\/thumb\/pic1_iphone3_thumb.jpg"},{"name":"Poza 2","target":"http:\/\/audifrance.fr","url":"http:\/\/test.res-novae.fr\/sfrplay\/upload\/image\/pic2_iphone3.jpg","url_thumb":"http:\/\/test.res-novae.fr\/sfrplay\/upload\/thumb\/pic2_iphone3_thumb.jpg"}]}
```

by getting the first element in the array

```
NSDictionary* dict = [statuses objectAtIndex:0];
```

and the keys in the dictionary should be "name", and "items". The object for "name" will be an NSString and the object for "items" will be an NSArray containing further NSDictionary objects describing each item.

Comment: What happens now when you NSLog statuses?

Answer (score 0):

There is a issue with your line

```
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

you have declared `responseString` as `NSString *responseString = [request responseString];`
and you are giving it as Data while allocating `json_string`